# Continuous but not compact operator on $L^2(0,\infty)$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Define the following operator on $L^2(0,\infty)$:

$$Tf(x)=\frac{1}{x} \int_0^xf(y)dy,\quad f\in L^2(0\infty).$$

I would like to see that it is continuous but **not** compact.

So, this is an integral operator with kernel $k(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}\mathbf1_{(0,x)}(y)$. The problem is that $k$ is not even in $L^2(0,\infty)^2$. Thus, the usual bound $\|Tf\|_2\leq \|k\|_2\cdot \|f\|_2$ does not work. Hence I am not even sure why the operator is well-defined.

I.e. why is $Tf$ even in $L^2(0,\infty)$? And how might we show continuity/non-compactness?

Comment: To obtain the continuity, you can use [Hardy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy's_inequality).

Answer (score 5):

Let $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|_{L^2}}f \in L^2(0,\infty)$. We have 
\begin{align*}
  \norm{Tf}^2 &= \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\int_0^\infty \frac 1{x^2} \abs{\int_0^x f(y)\, dy}^2 \, dx\\
           &\le \int_0^\infty \frac 1{x^2}\left(\int_0^x y^{1/4}y^{-1/4}\abs{f(y)}\, dy\right)^2 \, dx \\
           &\le \int_0^\infty \frac 1{x^2} \left[\left( \int_0^x y^{-1/2}\, dy\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^x y^{1/2}\abs{f(y)}^2 \, dy\right)^{1/2}\right]^2 \, dx\\
   &= \int_0^\infty \frac {2x^{1/2}}{x^2} \int_0^x y^{1/2}\abs{f(y)}^2 \, dy\, dx\\
   &= \int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty \frac 2{x^{3/2}} \, dx\cdot  y^{1/2}\abs{f(y)}^2 \, dy\\
   &= \int_0^\infty \frac 4{y^{1/2}} \cdot y^{1/2}\abs{f(y)}^2\, dy\\
   &= 4 \norm f^2 
\end{align*}
Hence, $\norm{Tf}\le 2\norm f$, proving the continuity of $T$.

To see that $T$ is not compact, let $f_n := n^{1/2} \chi_{[0,1/n]}$, then $\norm{f_n} = 1$ and 
$$ \norm{Tf_n - Tf_m}^2 \ge \int_0^{1/m} (m^{1/2} - n^{1/2})^2\, dx = \left(1 - \left(\frac nm\right)^{1/2}\right)^2 $$
So $(Tf_n)$ does not have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: How do you move from 5-th to 6-th line ? I can not see it

Comment: $$\int_y^\infty \frac 2{x^{3/2}}\, dx = \left[-\frac 4{x^{1/2}}\right]_y^\infty = \frac 4{y^{1/2}}$$

Comment: I meant another thing, but I saw it :)

Comment: What happens in the line above that, @martini? Great answer by the way!

Comment: In the line above that I did two steps at once, sry. On one side, we have 
$$ \int_0^x y^{-1/2}\, dy = 2x^{1/2}$$
giving 
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac1{x^2} \cdot 2x^{1/2} \int_0^x y^{1/2}|f(y)|^2\, dy\, dx $$ 
Now we use Fubini.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry @martini, I understood that step, but I didn't understand how you arrive at $$\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty \frac 2{x^{3/2}} \, dx\cdot  y^{1/2}\abs{f(y)}^2 \, dy$$

Comment: Fubini, as I said. For $g(x,y) = \frac 2{x^{3/2}}y^{1/2}|f(y)|^2$, we have
$$ \int_0^\infty \int_0^x g(x,y)\, dy \,dx = \int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty g(x,y)\, dx\, dy $$